# Curious outcome using OR statements in MySQL Matching

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am using a mysql match to grab entries from a mysql table that contain certain keywords in their title column. I used the OR option (+ AND -NOT Nil OR) for the mysql match but it seems to only work using one keyword.

Here's my output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM projects WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('Beautiful' 'birds' 'houses' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM projects WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('Beautiful' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+-----------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| id        | title                  | purl                                                                           | rurl                                                                              | rewards |
+-----------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| 978726622 | Beautiful birds houses | https://www.***** | https://www.**** |       4 |
+-----------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on this would be really appreciated. It doesn't make any sense to me that the OR statement is somehow restricting the output. Documentation is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: FULLTEXT works strangely when you have relatively small numbers of records to search. That confounds testing.  Does your `projects` table only have a few dozen records?

Comment: You have to use ONE expression there. `'Beautiful' 'birds' 'houses'` is not it. Use `... AGAINST ('Beautiful birds houses' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

Comment: Or `... AGAINST('+beautiful +bird +houses' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` if you want all those words.